# How to validate my android app as new app?

Tags: android, google-play

I have created an app which aggregates news using News.org API. That means my app is a news app.

Google asking to declare whether my app is news app or not.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9949730

> An app that declares itself as a "News" app on Google Play must be
> able to show clear ownership of the app and provide ownership
> information about in-app news content. if your app aggregates news published from other sources, you must indicate the original publisher of each article.
>
> 1. The website of the news publisher explicitly links to the
>    corresponding news app
> 2. App developer has claimed and verified the a
>    news publishers’ website domain
> 3. Documentation that validates an app
>    developer’s credentials as a news publisher (e.g., prior work, your
>    verifiable association with the press industry)

But I am an ordinary developer, it's not feasible for me to get relationships with the news sources.

I am showing news sources in my app, but Google rejected it and stopped me from updating my app.

What should I do now ? Did I miss anything or misunderstood ?

Comment: Have you integrated a license that shows, that you have the right to use the source? And you might check if you wrote to each news the real source. If this source is unknown, try it with the api you are using

Comment: What license ? I dont get it. I have also used google fact check api. Google still rejected my app althugh I was using Google's own api..

Comment: So, i think google wants news that are trustworthy and good. Your resources need to be from a famous company like Reuters or New York Times. The license i was taking about should may show that the api allows you to do that in a public app...